Does any permutation "cover" a permutation with less inversions?
Let $\mathcal{S}_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ objects. For any permutation $\pi\in\mathcal{S}_n$, define $E(\pi)=\{(i,j):\ i<j,\ \pi(i)>\pi(j)\}$ as the set of reversed pair of indices corresponding to $\pi$. With this definition, $|E(\pi)|$ -- the cardinality of $E(\pi)$ -- is just the inversion number of $\pi$.
True or Not: Given any $n\geq 1$ and $\pi\in\mathcal{S}_n$ with $|{E(\pi)}|\geq 1$, for any integer $k$ satisfying $0\leq k<|E(\pi)|$, there exists $\pi'\in\mathcal{S}_n$, such that
$$
E(\pi')\subseteq E(\pi)\quad \textit{and}\quad |E(\pi')|=k. 
$$
I have gone over the cases of $|E(\pi)|=1,2,3$, and have not found any counterexamples so far. Any answers or hints will be appreciated.

Hint: Think about which inversions involve $n$.

It's enough to do the case $k=|E(\pi)|-1$ by induction. Any nonidentity permutation $\pi$ must have an inversion of the form $\langle i, j\rangle$ where $\pi(i)= \pi(j)+1$ (I'm going to use $\langle i, j\rangle$ for ordered pairs to avoid confusion with transpositions $(i, j)$). Then $(\pi(j), \pi(j)+1) \circ \pi$ has exactly the same inversions as $\pi$ except that it does not have $\langle i, j\rangle$, so $E((\pi(j), \pi(j)+1)\pi)$ is a subset of $E(\pi)$ which is exactly one smaller.
There's another way to look at this problem.  Proposition 2.1 here, due to Kostant, is a beautiful characterisation of sets of inversions of elements of $S_n$ among subsets of $\Delta_n^+ = \{\langle i, j\rangle : 1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n\}$: they are the subsets $S$ such that both $S$ and $S^c=\Delta_n^+ \setminus S$ are transitive when thought of as relations on $1, 2, \ldots, n$.  We can re-prove the result from this point of view by showing that given any such nonempty $S$ it is possible to remove one element to form a set $S'$ which still has the property that $S'$ and $S'^c$ are transitive.
Suppose $S$ is a nonempty subset of $\Delta_n^+$ such that $S$ and $S^c$ are transitive.  I will sometimes write $aSb$ to mean $\langle a, b\rangle \in S$, and similarly for $S^c$.  Amongst all covering relations $\langle x, y\rangle \in S$ (that is, elements $\langle x, y\rangle$ of $S$ such that there is no $z$ with $\langle x, z\rangle, \langle z, y\rangle \in S$) choose one with $y-x$ is as large as possible. Certainly $S' = S \setminus \{\langle x, y\rangle\}$ still has the transitivity property, and I claim $S'^c = S^c \cup \{\langle x, y\rangle\}$ does too.
Suppose not, so either there is $\langle y, z \rangle$ in $S^c$ with $\langle x, z \rangle \in S$ or there is $\langle z, x\rangle \in S^c$ with $\langle z, y\rangle \in S$.  In the first case, $\langle x, z\rangle$ is a covering relation (if $xSw$ and $wSz$ then $wS^c y$ as $\langle x, y\rangle$ is a covering relation, so $wS^c y, y S^c z$, and therefore $xS^c z$ by transitivity of $S^c$, contradicting $xSw$) and $z-x>y-x$ contradicting the choice of $x$ and $y$. The second case is similar, completing the proof.

Talented ideas. You have my thanks!
